# want to create a map<String , Object> ,Object can be String and can be class Object

Tags: java

How want to create a `Map<String , Object>`.

In this map everytime the Object is a string. But Now I want to put a class in the object in addition to that. Is this a  good way to mix string and a class object? If yes, when I iterate through the map, how can I distiguish between class and string?

Comment: you can use if (object instanceof java.lang.String ) for distiguish between class and string.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to achieve. Your question suggests a Map where the keys are String, and the values are Object. This is a common and correct way, but I am not sure this is what you mean. Perhaps show some sample code to clarify your intent.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
...
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
        // Do something with entry.getKey() and entry.getValue()
    } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Class) {
        // Do something else with entry.getKey() and entry.getValue()
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Expecting either String or Class as entry value");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Every objects (excluding interfaces) in java extends `Object`, so your approach is correct.

To know whether an object is a string or other object type, use the `instanceof` keyword.

Example:

```
Map<String, Object> objectMap = ....;

for (String key :  objectMap.keySet()) {
    Object value = objectMap.get(key);
    if (value instanceof String) {
        System.out.println((String) value);
    } else if (value instanceof Class) {
        System.out.println("Class: " + ((Class)value).getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have `Object` as a value in Map you can add any object as value as String, Integer, Your custom class...

And to distiguish between class and string while iterating you can use `instance of` to check whether it is String or not.

ie:

```
Set<String> mapKeys = myMap.keySet();
for (String key :  mapKeys) {
    Object value = myMap.get(key);
    if (value instanceof String) {
        //value is of type String
    } else if (value instanceof MyClass) {
        //value is of type MyClass
    }
}
```